# What happens to the secret message at the end of the duration of the Illusory Script spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [*illusory script*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/illusory-script) spell allows one to hide a secret written message that either appears unintelligible or appears to be an unrelated message to anyone other than the intended recipient(s). The spell explains clearly what happens if the spell is dispelled:

> Should the spell be dispelled, the original script and the illusion both disappear.

This is certainly a handy security feature: dispelling the illusion won't reveal your secret message to snooping spellcaster. However, the spell is less clear about what happens at the end of the 10-day duration. A spell that ends due to reaching its duration is not "dispelled", so the above clause would not apply directly. The only reference to the spell's duration is in the first sentence:

> You write on parchment, paper, or some other suitable writing material and imbue it with a potent illusion that lasts for the duration.

**So, what happens when the duration of *illusory script* elapses?** Do the illusory script and the real message both disappear, as when the spell is dispelled, thus ensuring that no one other than the intended recipient(s) can ever read the message (without truesight)? Or does the illusion disappear, leaving the real message plainly readable by anyone?

Comment: Ooh. Now this is a good question. A small corresponding /r/dndnext thread with a few diverging conclusions (and no citations, just rulings): https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/6hiqhw/what_happens_to_illusory_script_after_its/

Answer (score 3):

## Both interpretations are feasible

The key is within this sentence:

> You write on parchment, paper, or some other suitable writing material and imbue it with a potent illusion that lasts for the duration.

What does the duration of "10 days" refer to? The illusion covering the writing.

The problem is, it is unclear whether the writing itself is included in the 10-day duration.

### Interpretation 1: Both original script and illusion disappear

This interpretation is supported by the fact that dispelling the spell removes the original script. The original script is not *real* and when the spell ends, the original script also disappear.

### Interpretation 2: Original script remains

The argument for this interpretation is that the writing is mundane, but covered by an illusion from the spell. When the illusion expires, the original script remains.

---

Both interpretations have equally strong arguments supporting them, so **you can pick whichever**. I myself favor the latter interpretation.

Comment: Comments are for requesting clarification or suggesting improvements, not voicing “I disagree” — leave your own answer if you disagree.

Answer (score -3):

### *Dispel Magic* ends a spell, Both scripts disappear

The description of *Dispel Magic* states (PHB 234):

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

This is the entire description of what *Dispel Magic* does.  Everything else in the description of this spell only describes the mechanics of dice rolls and spell slots.

Since *Dispel Magic* causes a spell to end, the results of ending the spell and dispelling the spell would be the same unless stated otherwise.

Comment: *"This is the entire description of what Dispel Magic does."* no it is not. Specific beats general, so specific description of what dispel magic do to illusory script changes / adds to dispel magic mechanics. And because rules only do what they say they do, it applies *only* to dispel magic. Maybe results of spell aging out are like you wrote, but it would be a coincidence.

Comment: @molot The phrasing in the description is inclusive of both casting dispel magic and ending the spell. You're making it far more complicated than it is. There's  nothing that indicates that dispelling and ending the spell are different.

Comment: "There's nothing that indicates that dispelling and ending the spell are different." - I never argued there is. I'm just saying there is nothing that proves or even indicates it is the same, either. And I guess that's not only me, given that I wasn't only one, or even first one to downvote.  I believed you deserve an explanation of my vote. I won't engage in further discussion. We're not on the message boards or forum, after all.

Comment: @molot The description of dispel magic states they are the same.

Comment: The description of *dispel magic* does not state that dispelling and ending a spell are the same. It states that it ends the spell. If there was no difference, then *illusory script* would say "when the spell ends", similar to other spells like [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) that produce effects at the end of the spell.

Comment: @RyanThompson, There's no way that I read that and I think they don't mean the same thing.  It's a somewhat ambiguous statement and it doesn't happen anywhere else in the PHB so it's not surprising that different people interpret it in different ways.  I know how I interpret it and I know why. I'm totally o.k. with us not agreeing on how to interpret it.

Comment: You can interpret it how you want, but "A causes B" is a different statement from "A is the same as B." *Dispel magic* says the former, not the latter.

Comment: @RyanThompson Can you offer an example where the semantic difference has an impact on game play?

Comment: I already gave an example in a previous comment: *haste* has an effect that occurs "when the spell ends" while *illusory script* says that something happens "should the spell be dispelled". It's possible this is an oversight on the part of the writers, but if we take it at face value, it suggests that there is a distinction.

Comment: @RyanThompson The description of haste only shows a difference in semantics. It does not state any difference between a spell ending and a spell being dispelled. You're assuming there is a difference but it is not stated anywhere.

Comment: It is also not stated anywhere that ending a spell is equivalent to dispelling it. Based on the principle that [there aren't secret rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107647/40516), there is no reason to regard them as equivalent when there is nothing saying so.

Comment: @ryanthompson When you cast dispel PHB 141: **the spell on the target ends**. It's not a secret at all, it's very clearly stated. I appreciate your perspective but this convo is going in circles and I'm going to bow out.

Comment: PHB 234 not 141.